# How do I replace all occourences of a symbol except the last one using sed?

Tags: sed

For example, I got a line like this:

```
44567743346_567864_56788_5677_3
```

I want to change all the `_` into `:`, except for the last one would change into `\`. The expected output is:

```
44567743346:567864:56788:5677\3
```

Comment: Will it always end in a 3?

Comment: No, thats the question.

Comment: Why do change your question in a comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ echo '44567743346_567864_56788_5677_3' | sed -r 's|_|:|g; s|:([^:]*)$|\\\1|'
44567743346:567864:56788:5677\3
```

This uses two sed substitution commands.  The first, `s|_|:|g` changes all underlines to colons.  The second, `s|:([^:]*)$|\\\1|` finds the last colon and changes it to a backslash.

#### Modifying every fourth line of a file this way

```
sed -r '1~4{s|_|:|g; s|:([^:]*)$|\\\1|;}' file
```

To modify the file in-place:

```
sed -i -r '1~4{s|_|:|g; s|:([^:]*)$|\\\1|;}' file
```

Comment: In my actual script, I write sed -i '1~4s|_|:|g; 1~4s|:([^:]*)$|\\\1|' ${1}, since I need to change all the first lines of every 4 lines, but it didnot wrok:(

Comment: @LucasLau Please add the `-r` option to enable extended regex and try again.

Comment: Thx man! Really help

Answer (score 2):

If you know the count of the last occurrence of `_` e.g. in your example the last `_` is the 4th `_` in the line, you can do :

```
sed 's/_/\\/4; s/_/:/g' file.txt
```

Here we have first converted the 4th (last) occurrence of `_` to `\`, then the remaining occurrences of `_` are converted to `:`.

For example :

```
$ echo '44567743346_567864_56788_5677_3' | sed 's/_/\\/4; s/_/:/g'
44567743346:567864:56788:5677\3
```

---

On the other hand if you don't know the position of the last occurrence of `_`, you can greedily match upto the last occurrence of `_`, replace it with `\` and then replace the rest with `:` :

```
sed -r 's/^(.*)_/\1\\/; s/_/:/g' file.txt
```

For example :

```
$ echo '44567743346_567864_56788_5677_3' | sed -r 's/^(.*)_/\1\\/; s/_/:/g'
44567743346:567864:56788:5677\3
```

Answer (score 2):

A **Simple One** Using `sed`

`echo "44567743346_567864_56788_5677_3" | rev | sed "s/_/:/2g" | sed 's/_/\\/' | rev`

---

Now let's see *how it works:-*

**1)** `rev` reverses the string,

it becomes `3_7765_88765_468765_64334776544`

**2)** `sed "s/_/:/2g` replaces all occurrence of `_` to `:` except the first occurrence in reversed string,

it becomes, `3_7765:88765:468765:64334776544`

**3)** Next `sed` i.e. `sed 's/_/\\/'` replaces just the first occurrence of `_` to `\`.

It becomes, `3\7765:88765:468765:64334776544`

**4)** `rev` reverses this processed string

Now, final string is:-

`44567743346:567864:56788:5677\3`

Now, its **done**!

**Note**: It doesn't give much efficiency. Its here just because its **simple**

Answer (score 0):

Why `sed` if it's simpler using `awk`?

```
awk -F_ '{printf "%s",$1; for(i=2;i<NF;i++){printf ":%s",$i}; printf "\\%s\n",$NF}' your_input_file
```

And as you said in **a comment?** you need only every fourth line

```
awk -F_ '(NR % 4) == 1 {printf "%s",$1; for(i=2;i<NF;i++){printf ":%s",$i}; printf "\\%s\n",$NF; next} {print}'  your_input_file
```

---

*Example*

Input file

```
% cat foo
1_44567743346_567864_56788_5677_3
2_908798_08098_878_24332_24_24244_22
3_44567743346_567864_56788_5677_3
4_908798_08098_878_24332_24_24244_22
1_44567743346_567864_56788_5677_3
2_908798_08098_878_24332_24_24244_22
3_44567743346_567864_56788_5677_3
4_908798_08098_878_24332_24_24244_22
1_44567743346_567864_56788_5677_3
2_908798_08098_878_24332_24_24244_22
3_44567743346_567864_56788_5677_3
4_908798_08098_878_24332_24_24244_22
1_44567743346_567864_56788_5677_3
2_908798_08098_878_24332_24_24244_22
3_44567743346_567864_56788_5677_3
4_908798_08098_878_24332_24_24244_22
```

Command output to change every fourth line

```
% awk -F_ '(NR % 4) == 1 {printf "%s",$1; for(i=2;i<NF;i++){printf ":%s",$i}; printf "\\%s\n",$NF; next} {print}' foo
1:44567743346:567864:56788:5677\3
2_908798_08098_878_24332_24_24244_22
3_44567743346_567864_56788_5677_3
4_908798_08098_878_24332_24_24244_22
1:44567743346:567864:56788:5677\3
2_908798_08098_878_24332_24_24244_22
3_44567743346_567864_56788_5677_3
4_908798_08098_878_24332_24_24244_22
1:44567743346:567864:56788:5677\3
2_908798_08098_878_24332_24_24244_22
3_44567743346_567864_56788_5677_3
4_908798_08098_878_24332_24_24244_22
1:44567743346:567864:56788:5677\3
2_908798_08098_878_24332_24_24244_22
3_44567743346_567864_56788_5677_3
4_908798_08098_878_24332_24_24244_22
```

Command output to change each line

```
% awk -F_ '{printf "%s",$1; for(i=2;i<NF;i++){printf ":%s",$i}; printf "\\%s\n",$NF}' foo                               
1:44567743346:567864:56788:5677\3
2:908798:08098:878:24332:24:24244\22
3:44567743346:567864:56788:5677\3
4:908798:08098:878:24332:24:24244\22
1:44567743346:567864:56788:5677\3
2:908798:08098:878:24332:24:24244\22
3:44567743346:567864:56788:5677\3
4:908798:08098:878:24332:24:24244\22
1:44567743346:567864:56788:5677\3
2:908798:08098:878:24332:24:24244\22
3:44567743346:567864:56788:5677\3
4:908798:08098:878:24332:24:24244\22
1:44567743346:567864:56788:5677\3
2:908798:08098:878:24332:24:24244\22
3:44567743346:567864:56788:5677\3
4:908798:08098:878:24332:24:24244\22
```

Answer (score 0):

Works in any line length:

```bsh
$ echo "44567743346_567864_56788_5677_3" | sed -E 's/^(.*)_/\1\\/; s/_/:/g'
44567743346:567864:56788:5677\3
```

Comment: Can you explain what these regexes do and why they work?